# Mysql query to get duplicate customer entries caused by typo(s) in random fields

Tags: mysql

I am sitting in front of a customer table that looks like this, among other things:

| ID | title | salutation | first name | last name | name | street | zip | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Prof. Dr. | Herr | Ingo Torben | Wuse | Ingo Torben Wuse | Sonnenlute 10 A | 01005 | Frutil OT Puttin |
| 02 | Prof. Dr. | Herr | Ingo | Wuse | Ingo Wuse | Sonnenlute 10 A | 01005 | Frutil |

My issue is customers end up twice in there (this is not on our hands) because of typos in 1 or more fields, but I can't just look for duplicates because many people can and will live at the same address.

So I thought about looking for rows that have the same SALUTATION, either FIRST NAME or LAST NAME identical and 2 matches across STREET;ZIP;LOCATION.

However, that would get me a thousand `roberts` for `new york city`.

I'm not sure if MySQL can do the job alone here, c# would be fine as well.

In the above example I realized my solution doesn't work:

As you can see, he decided to use all of his first names this time and for the location he added info as to what area his location belongs to.

Up to this point all I did was look for rows with the same first name, last name, street and city, but I realized that cannot work.

The correct way would be to teach the client to not let customers write to their database directly, but...

It doesn't have to catch every possible duplicate, I don't think that's even possible, but the most obvious ones or just a huge improvement over my super basic implementation would help a lot.

Thank you very much for your suggestions!

Comment: This is a very broad subject and mysql is not the best tool for this. You need to do some research into fuzzy matching and you need to develop the business logic first to determine when you think two entries are similar enough to consider them the same. You probably need to include some human checks for some cases where the similarity score is high, but not high enough for an automated decision.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's already a few wiki articles to read.